# Import/Setting background image to windows form cause run slow

Tags: c#, winforms

I import background image to every forms in my project now my programs runs slow?

How can I fix this?

the format for the image is png.

Any things to consider in to doing this? to solve the issue? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Form,set property `DoubleBuffered` to `true`

> Buffered graphics require that the updated graphics data is first
>   written to a buffer. The data in the graphics buffer is then quickly
>   written to displayed surface memory. The relatively quick switch of
>   the displayed graphics memory typically reduces the flicker that can
>   otherwise occur.

Instead of using `PNG` format use `JPEG` format with Quality 12(final image quality is like `PNG` format),your image size decrease and your form load faster.

Comment: I see, how about the image? is the format good? or is there any more faster to load than PNG?

Comment: Convert Your image to jpeg with quality 12,with this your image size decrease and your form load faster.with quality 12 your image quality is like png